# Logged in user ID as post ID

Tags: php, functions, query-posts, get-posts

Is there a way to automatically insert the current user ID as the post category name or maybe have WordPress display only the post with a category name that matches the current logged user ID?

```
<?php

    $query = new WP_Query('category_name=current-user-id');

    if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

    ?> 

     <?php

       the_content( __('Read the rest of this page »', 'template'));

      endwhile; endif;

     wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get information on the currently logged in user using the get_currentuserinfo() function.

For example:

```
<?php
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  $username = $current_user->user_login;
  $user_id = $current_user->ID;
?>
```

You can then use $username or $user_id in your custom loop.

```
<?php 
   // assign the variable as current category
   $category = $user_id;

  // concatenate the query
  $args = 'cat=' . $category;

  // run the query
  query_posts( $args );

  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

 // do something here

 endwhile;

 endif;
 wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

Comment: Henry, it doesn't seem to be working and I don't know why.

Comment: Which file are you updating with the code?

Comment: With few changes, it works as exactly as I want. In the end, It was your(henrywright) Idea.

Comment: Glad you were able to customise the code to work for you!